# Unexpected Value 'SomeModule' imported by the module 'SomeModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular

Migrating Angular v8 to v10. And trying to import angular library to main Project. But library module is not found and im getting Please add @NgModule Annotation Error

Comment: kindly share more information about the problem

Comment: Dear @OwenKelvin
Created one Angular 10 Project(Prj1). Ideally this will be used as a Library in another Main project.  In Prj1, Have created few components, services  and those are added into one module name called SharedModule. Now using ng Packagr , have created tarball file successfully . in Next comment plz

Comment: using npm install, Prj1 tarball has installed in Main project and im trying to use SharedModule here. I have imported SharedModule in Main project. But while execute ng Serve im getting 

Unexpected Value 'SharedModule in node_modules/LibraryPkg/module.d.ts' imported by the module 'SomeModule'(Mainproject module). Please add a @NgModule annotation.


The entire project was running fine in Angular 8; I just trying to migrate from 8 to Ang 10

Comment: can you share your `SharedModule` code?

Comment: import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";


import { SharedComponentModule } from "./components/component.module";
import { SharedServiceModule } from "./services/service.module";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [sampleComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule]
  exports: [SharedComponentModule ,SharedServiceModule ]
})
export class SharedModule {}

Comment: I just noticed that, After creating tarbal file using ng-packager command, I dont find meta.json file in Ang 10 version. But earlier version i could find such file, Is that could be the reason?

Comment: If you copy pasted the code it appears there is no comma between `[CommonModule]` and `exports`

Comment: Good Look! . But in actual code it has

Comment: @OwenKelvin --  Thank you for looking into my concern and finally i found the reason for this issue- As I said meta.json is the key cause;